# Get all records by date ignoring the time in DateTime in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, jodatime

I'm using Grails Joda date time plugin I want to fetch all record for a day ignoring the time precision in the Date. Whats the best way to do it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you fetching these records from the database with GORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Record {
  DateTime dateField

  def getAllRecordsForOneDay(aDay = new DateTime()) {
     def localDate = new LocalDate(aDay);
     Record.findAllDateFieldBetween(localDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(), localDate.plusDays(1).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay())
     //Or with criteria
     Record.withCriteria {
       between 'dateField', localDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(), localDate.plusDays(1).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()
     }

  }

}
```

Comment: localDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay() and  localDate.toDateTimeAtMidnight() both return same result so the query doesn't return anything :(